# ¿Como devuelvo algo con el método return y luego cambio su valor a 0?

Tags: java, bluej

Quería saber como puedo devolver un valor con `return` y después poner el estado de ese atributo a `0`.

Por ejemplo, que devuelva el valor del número de ruedas `4` y que luego ponga ese mismo valor a `0`.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask]. Debes incluir la parte relevante del código que estás implementando. Puedes leer [mcve] como referencia. Saludos

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Ten en cuenta lo que te ha dicho @MauricioContreras para esta y para futuras preguntas. Dado que preguntas algo sencillo, puedes hacerlo así: `int nRuedas=elMetodo(elParametro); nRuedas=0;` Listo. Si no es eso, por favor edita la pregunta, pon el código y explica mejor el problema. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una vez que haces un return el resto del código por debajo de él es inaccesible, el IDE que utilices te lo marcará como error.

Pero puedes hacer lo que quieres de siguiente modo:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Coche coche = new Coche();
        System.out.println(coche.updatenRuedas());
        System.out.println(coche.getnRuedas());
    }
}

class Coche {
    int nRuedas = 4;

    public Coche()  {}

    public void setnRuedas(int nRuedas) {
        this.nRuedas = nRuedas;
    }

    public int getnRuedas() {
        return nRuedas;
    }

    public int updatenRuedas() {
        int ruedas = this.nRuedas;
        this.nRuedas = 0;
        return ruedas;
    }
}
```

Ya que el metodo  updatenRuedas hace lo que comentas.

También puedes llamar al metodo get y luego al set, que hace lo mismo, pero sería en dos llamadas distintas:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Coche coche = new Coche();
    System.out.println(coche.getnRuedas());
    coche.setnRuedas(0);
    System.out.println(coche.getnRuedas());
}
```

Comment: Muschisimas gracias, era justo lo que necesitaba.

Comment: Me alegro de haber ayudado . Marcala como correcta y votala para que ayude en un futuro a los que tengan la misma duda.